# Anaconda Prompt Cannot run - Permission Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, permissions, anaconda

it seems like I can't do anything with Anaconda. I cannot open the navigator because clicking the shortcut doesn't do anything. I tried uninstalling by running conda install anaconda-clean but I get the following error:

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\rashi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2lkbh2gh'

I cannot install any new libraries in my juptyter notebook or anything.

I've attached images of the prompt I put into the Anaconda prompt.

[This is the prompt i put and the first half of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqJwK.png)

[This is the second half of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Ybd.png)

Any code involving anaconda yields the error i showed in the images. Installing a library, or trying to install anaconda clean.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.